# jquery lightbox clone not working in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I'm using [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto) image gallery in my website Here is my [Website](http://houston3drenderings.com/index.php?m=list&a=index&id=3#) 
Just open it and click any image after loading the whole page image will show in a dialog box. Now, open console and select mobile device and check it this is working but when I open in mobile browser this is not working good. I'm using google chrome browser both in desktop and in mobile. Why this is not working in mobile browser ?

Comment: i gues the prettyPhoto plugin u use is not sportive for the mobile view

Comment: @nivendha No, its supported. It's working but now suddenly it's stop working.